# Zeroes in interval

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion, counting

Your task is to write a function or program that takes two non-negative integers `i` and `k` (`i` ≤ `k`), and figure out how many zeroes you'd write if you wrote all whole numbers from `i` to `k` (inclusive) in your base of choice on a piece of paper. Output this integer, the number of zeroes, to stdout or similar.

`-30%` if you also accept a third argument `b`, the integer base to write down the numbers in. At least two bases must be handled to achieve this bonus.

- You may accept the input in any base you like, and you may change the base between test cases.
- You may accept the arguments `i`, `k` and optionally `b` in any order you like.
- Answers must handle at least one base that is not unary.

Test cases (in base 10):

```
i k -> output
10 10 -> 1
0 27 -> 3
100 200 -> 22
0 500 -> 92
```

This is code-golf; fewest bytes win.

Comment: If you can go with whatever base you'd like from case to case, couldn't you do each in base k and print 0 or 1, depending on whether i = 0?

Comment: You might want to exclude unary as a base, or else this problem is trivial: get inputs, print 0.

Comment: Can you add some test cases for other bases?

Comment: I think this would be more interesting if the base argument were required. "Base of your choice" is weird to me.

Comment: Yes, @AlexA. but too late to change that now, 10 answers in.

Comment: Can we get input in unary?

Comment: @ThomasKwa yes, unary input is ok

Comment: @Mego According to Wikipedia, "in order to represent a number N, an arbitrarily chosen symbol representing 1 is repeated N times". It would actually make the most sense to use `0`, since there is no `2` symbol in base 2, no `3` in base 3, etc. So it makes sense that base 1 has no `1`.

Answer (score 17):

### Jelly, 1 byte

```
¬
```

This uses base `k+2`, in which case there's a single 0 iff `i` is 0. It takes two arguments, but applies the logical NOT to only the first one.

If we don't want to cheat:

#### 7 bytes - 30% = 4.9

*-1.1 points by @Dennis*

```
rb⁵$¬SS
```

This gets the bonus.

```
             dyadic link:
r            inclusive range
 b⁵$           Convert all to base input.
    ¬          Vectorized logical NOT
     S         Sum up 0th digits, 1st digits, etc.
      S        Sum all values
```

Comment: This is the second Jelly program I've written on my phone.

Comment: Damn, 1 byte?  Give us a chance.

Comment: This can be easily done in very few bytes in any other language. I say stick to the non-cheating version.

Comment: @ETHproductions The rules of the question *explicitly* allow doing this. Cheaty or not, it's the answer the rules call for.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, 36 bytes

```py
lambda a,b:`range(a,b+1)`.count('0')
```

Credit to **muddyfish** for the `` trick.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! This is a nice first answer. :)

Comment: Wow! I didn't know it's working!

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>3</s> 1 byte

Uses base `k+2` like the Jelly answer, Code:

```
_
```

Explanation:

```
_  # Logical NOT operator
```

**3 byte non-cheating version:**

Code:

```
Ÿ0¢
```

Explanation:

```
Ÿ    # Inclusive range
 0¢  # Count zeroes
```

---

The bonus gives me **3.5 bytes** due to a bug:

```
ŸB)0¢
```

Explanation:

```
Ÿ      # Inclusive range
 B     # Convert to base input
  )    # Wrap into an array (which should not be needed)
   0¢  # Count zeroes
```

Uses CP-1252 encoding.

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Explanation added

Answer (score 5):

## Japt, 3 bytes

```
+!U
```

Uses base `k+2`, as the Jelly answer. There is a zero iff `i==0`. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=KyFV&input=MCA1MDA=)

#### Better version, <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
UòV ¬è'0
```

This one uses base 10. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VfJWIKzoJzA=&input=MCA1MDAgMTA=)

#### Bonus version, <s>14</s> 12 bytes - 30% = 8.4

```
UòV msW ¬è'0
```

Sadly, with the golfing I did, the bonus is no longer worth it... [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VfJWIG1zVyCs6Ccw&input=MCA1MDAgMTA=)

#### How it works

```
UòV msW ¬è'0   // Implicit: U = start int, V = end int, W = base
UòV            // Create the inclusive range [U..V].
    msW        // Map each item by turning it into a base-W string.
        ¬      // Join into a string.
         è'0   // Count the number of occurances of the string "0".
```

Answer (score 5):

### ES6, <s>91</s> 86 - 30% = 60.2 bytes

```
(i,k,b=10)=>([...Array(k+1-i)].map((_,n)=>(i+n).toString(b))+'0').match(/0/g).length-1
```

Or save 3 (2.1) bytes if b doesn't need to default to 10.

Best non-bonus version I could do was 65 bytes:

```
(i,k)=>([...Array(k+1).keys()].slice(i)+'0').match(/0/g).length-1
```

Edit: Saved 5 bytes by using @edc65's zero-counting trick.

Comment: As I don't manage to get votes for my answer, I'll upvote yours (at least there my name inside)

Answer (score 4):

### Seriously, 10 bytes

```
'0,,u@xεjc
```

Explanation:

```
'0,,u@xεjc
'0,,u       push "0", i, k+1
     @x     swap i and k+1, range(i, k+1)
       εjc  join on empty string and count 0s
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=JzAsLHVAeM61amM&input=MAoyNw)

With bonus: 11.9 bytes

```
'0,,u@x,╗`╜@¡`Mεjc
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=JzAsLHVAeCzilZdg4pWcQMKhYE3OtWpj&input=MAoyNwoy)

Explanation:

```
'0,,u@x,╗`╜@¡`MΣc
'0,,u@x             push "0", range(i, k+1)
       ,╗           push b to register 0
         `   `M     map:
          ╜@¡         push b, push string of a written in base b
               Σc   sum (concat for strings), count 0s
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 46 - 30% = 32.2 bytes

You could probably golf this more, but at least I get the 30% bonus!

```
->i,k,b{((i..k).map{|a|a.to_s b}*"").count ?0}
```

...or without the bonus (27 bytes.)

```
->i,k{([*i..k]*"").count ?0}
```

Tips are welcome, still learning this whole "Ruby" thing.

Comment: Nice answer, you don't need the splat operator when using map, this could save 1 byte. `(i..k)` is as good as `[*i..k]` in the first case.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>12</s> <s>10</s> 3 bytes

```
li!
```

This uses the shortcut @ThomasKwa does.

If this is not allowed, then here is a 10 byte answer.

```
q~),>s'0e=
```

Nice and short! Works like @Mego's Seriously answer.

Thanks @Dennis!

Had fun writing my first CJam answer!

[Try it here!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cX4pLD5zJzBlPQ&input=MAoyNw)

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL, 394 Bytes (No bonus)

I figure *'why not*', right?

```
DECLARE @i INT, @k INT SET @i = 100 SET @k = 200  WITH g AS (SELECT @i AS n UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM g WHERE n+1<=@k ) SELECT LEN(n) AS c FROM (SELECT STUFF((SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(n, 1, ''), 2, ''), 3, ''), 4, ''), 5, ''), 6, ''), 7, ''), 8, ''), 9, ''), ' ', '') FROM g FOR XML PATH ('')) ,1,0,'') n ) a OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

And the friendly one:

```
-- CG!

DECLARE @i INT, @k INT 
SET @i = 100
SET @k = 200

WITH g AS 
(
    SELECT @i AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM g WHERE n+1<=@k
)

SELECT LEN(n) AS c FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        STUFF((SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(n, 1, ''), 2, ''), 3, ''), 4, ''), 5, ''), 6, ''), 7, ''), 8, ''), 9, ''), ' ', '')
FROM g FOR XML PATH ('')) ,1,0,'') n
) a

OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: that's dedication.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 6.3 bytes, with bonus (9 bytes - 30%)

```
/sjRQ}EE0
```

Explanation:

```
  jRQ     - [conv_base(Q, d) for d in V]
     }EE  - inclusive_range(eval(input), eval(input))
 s        - sum(^, [])
/       0 - ^.count(0)
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jRQ%7DEE&input=10%0A10%0A20&debug=0)

Or 7 bytes without the bonus:

```
/`}EE\0
```

Explanation:

```
  }EE   - inclusive_range(eval(input), eval(input))
 `      - repr(^)
/    \0 - ^.count("0")
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2F%60%7DEE%5C0&input=0%0A27&debug=0)

[Or use a test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2F%60%7DEE%5C0&input=0%0A27&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=10%0A10%0A0%0A27%0A100%0A200%0A0%0A500&debug=0&input_size=2)

Comment: I think getting the bonus is worth it: `/sjRQ}EE0`

Comment: Ehh, it's the same code with a base conversion, I'm pretty sure you know what you're doing, just the problem of a bonus forcing you to try different stuff and count... :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 26 bytes

```
,{,.e?}?:1frcS:0xlI,Sl-I=.
```

Takes input as a list `[i,k]`.

#### Explanation

```
,{    }?:1f                § Unify the output with a list of all inputs which verify the
                           § predicate between brackets {...} with output set as the input
                           § of the main predicate

  ,.e?                     § Unify the input with a number between i and k with the ouput
                           § being the list [i,k]

           rcS             § Reverse the list and concatenate everything into a single
                           § number (we reverse it to not lose the leading 0 if i = 0 when
                           § we concatenate into a single number). Call this number S.

              :0xlI        § Remove all occurences of 0 from S, call I the length of this new
                           § number with no zeros

                   ,Sl-I=. § Output the length of S minus I.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 48 bytes - 30% = 33.6

```
f(i,k,b)=sum(j->sum(c->c<49,[base(b,j)...]),i:k)
```

This is a function that accepts three integers and returns an integer. One of the arguments specifies the base, so this qualifies for the bonus.

Ungolfed:

```
function f(i, k, b)
    # For each j in the inclusive range i to k, convert j to base
    # b as a string, splat the string into a character array, and
    # compare each character to the ASCII code 49 (i.e. '1'). The
    # condition will only be true if the character is '0'. We sum
    # these booleans to get the number of zeros in that number,
    # then we sum over the set of sums to get the result.
    sum(j -> sum(c -> c < 49, [base(b, j)...]), i:k)
end
```

Implementing the bonus yields a score just barely better than the not implementing it (34 bytes):

```
f(i,k)=sum(c->c<49,[join(i:k)...])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Seriously, 2 bytes

This might be taking the Jelly answer trick to the limit, but here is a simple 2 byte Seriously answer.

```
,Y
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LFk&input=MAoyNw)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 50 (71 - 30%)

```js
(n,k,b)=>eval("for(o=0;n<=k;++n)o+=n.toString(b)").match(/0/g).length-1
```

*No bonus, base k+2* is 10 bytes `(i,k)=>+!i`

*No bonus, unary* is 8 bytes `(i,k)=>0`

**TEST**

```js
f=(n,k,b)=>eval("for(o=0;n<=k;++n)o+=n.toString(b)").match(/0/g).length-1

function go() {
  var i=I.value.match(/\d+/g)
  R.textContent = f(i[0],i[1],i[2])
}

go()
```

```html
i,k,b:<input id=I value='0,500,10' oninput="go()">
<span id=R></span>
```

Comment: If you move the `o='0'` before the loop your code continues to work even when `k<i`.

Comment: @Neil nice, but the spec says `(i ≤ k)`. *Update* I tried this but in fact it does not work for k<i

Comment: Well, it worked for me (and I know the spec guarantees that i <= k, but your code crashes when k < i; by comparison my code only crashes when k < i - 1 !)

Comment: @Neil uh ok now I get it. It does not give a sensible answer but at least does not crash

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can save 8 bytes with this: `(i,k,b)=>eval("for(n=i;n<=k;++n)o+=n.toString(b)").match(/0/g).length`. In this case, var `o` needs to be `undefined` in the context of execution.

Comment: @ForcentVintier you need a 0 in the string to match, try calling the function with `(1,9,10)`

Comment: My bad then! Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @ForcentVintier anyway after your input I revised the code saving some bytes

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 50 Bytes

supports decimal only

```
<?=substr_count(join(range($argv[1],$argv[2])),0);
```

### supports decimal and binary with Bonus 63

```
<?=substr_count(join(array_map([2=>decbin,10=>""][$argv[3]],range($argv[1],$argv[2]))),0);
```

### supports decimal,hexadecimal, octal and binary with Bonus 77.7

```
<?=substr_count(join(array_map([2=>decbin,8=>decoct,10=>"",16=>dechex][$argv[3]],range($argv[1],$argv[2]))),0);
```

### supports base 2 - 36 with Bonus 78.4

```
<?=substr_count(join(array_map(function($i){return base_convert($i,10,$_GET[2]);},range($_GET[0],$_GET[1]))),0);
```

Comment: Nice collection! Care to do a version 3a including base 64? :D

Comment: @Titus How is the order of base 64? Why not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85 or make a little more with all printable ascii chars

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 52.

Tried to implement the bonus, but it doesn't seem to be worth it.

```
lambda a,b:''.join(map(str,range(a,b+1))).count('0')
```

With test cases:

```
assert f(10, 10) == 1
assert f(0, 27) == 3
assert f(100, 200) == 22
assert f(0, 500) == 92
```

Comment: I literally never heard about the assert statement before this comment. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

### Lua 74 bytes

```
z,c=io.read,""for a=z(),z()do c=c..a end o,b=string.gsub(c,"0","")print(b)
```

There's gotta be a more effective way to do this...

I thought I was really onto something here:

```
c,m,z=0,math,io.read for a=z(),1+z()do c=c+((m.floor(a/10))%10==0 and 1 or a%100==0 and 1 or a%10==0 and 1 or 0) end print(c)
```

But alas... It keeps getting longer and longer as I realize there's more and more zeroes I forgot about...

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, <s>56</s> <s>54</s> <s>51</s> <s>48</s> 42 bytes

```
param($i,$k)(-join($i..$k)-split0).count-1
```

Takes input, creates a range with `$i..$k` then `-join`s that together into a string, followed by a regex `-split` command that separates the string into an array by slicing at the `0`s. We encapsulate that with `().count-1` to measure how many zeros. That's left on the pipeline, and output is implicit.

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @ConnorLSW*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@1@QWJSYq6GSqaOSramhm5WfmQfk6OkBebrFBTmZJQaaesn5pXkluob///83@G9qYAAA)

---

Base-handling in PowerShell is [limited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) and doesn't support arbitrary bases, so I'm not going for the bonus.

Comment: `param($i,$k)(-join($i..$k)-split'0').Length-1` works for me, -3, or use `.Count-1` to save even more, haven't tested that yet though.

Comment: @ConnorLSW Thanks! Don't need the quotes around `'0'`, so that trimmed off a few more.

Comment: nice one, I always forget powershell handles numbers like that.

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 7 bytes

Replace `♂` with `\x11`. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=WmwRc2pKMA)

```
Zl♂sjJ0
   sjJ  inclusive range between two numeric inputs
  ♂      chopped into single-length elements
Zl    0  and count the number of zeroes
        implicitly printed
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 22 bytes

```
{+/'0'⍷∊0⍕¨(⍺-1)↓⍳⍵}
```

This is a monadic function that accepts the range boundaries on the left and right and returns an integer.

Ungolfed:

```
           (⍺-1)↓⍳⍵}  ⍝ Construct the range ⍺..⍵ by dropping the first
                      ⍝ ⍺-1 values in the range 1..⍵
       ∊0⍕¨           ⍝ Convert each number to a string
{+/'0'⍷               ⍝ Count the occurrences of '0' in the string
```

[Try it here](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%7B+/%270%27%u2377%u220A0%u2355%A8%28%u237A-1%29%u2193%u2373%u2375%7D%20%u22C4%20100%20f%20200&run)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 29 bytes

```
i#k=sum[1|'0'<-show=<<[i..k]]
```

I'm using [base 10](http://cowbirdsinlove.com/43).

Usage example: `100 # 200` -> `22`

How it works: turn each element in the list from `i` to `k` into it's string representation, concatenate into a single string, take a `1` for every char `'0'` and sum those `1`s.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 7 (10 bytes − 30% bonus)

```
2$:i:qYA~z
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MiQ6aTpxWUF-eg&input=MTAwCjIwMAoxMA)

This works in [release 11.0.2](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/11.0.2), which is earlier than this challenge.

#### Explanation

```
2$:      % implicitly input two numbers and generate inclusive range
i:q      % input base b and generate vector [0,1,...,b-1]
YA       % convert range to base b using symbols 0,1,...,b-1. Gives 2D array
~        % logical negation. Zeros become 1, rest of symbols become 0
z        % number of nonzero elements in array
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab: 27 bytes

```
@(q,w)nnz(num2str(q:w)==48)
```

creates a vector from lower number to larger one, then converts all numbers to string and counts all the '0' symbols.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 23 bytes

```perl6
{+($^i..$^k).comb(/0/)}
```

1. creates a Range ( `$^i..$^k` )
2. joins the values with spaces implicitly ( `.comb` is a Str method )
3. creates a list of just the zeros ( `.comb(/0/)` )
4. returns the number of elems in that list ( `+` )

#### Usage:

```perl6
my &zero-count = {…}

for (10,10), (0,27), (100,200), (0,500), (0,100000) {
  say zero-count |@_
}
```

```
1
3
22
92
38895
```

Comment: You know, that comment at the end of your code makes it seem longer...

Comment: @ETHproductions I usually do that so that if I come up with more than one way to do things that I can see if it is shorter than others. I just keep adding more ways to do it until I come up with what I think is the shortest way.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 39 bytes, 27.3 with bonus

```
Count[#~Range~#2~IntegerDigits~#3,0,2]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx37x362.aspx) 112 Bytes

```cs
int z(int i,int k)=>String.Join("",Enumerable.Range(i,k-i+1)).Count(c=>c=='0')
```

1. Create a string with numbers from the first number up to the last number
2. Count the zero characters in the string

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I'm not super familiar with C# but I think you could probably save a few bytes if you removed some of the spaces.

Comment: thank you 0, you are right but only a couple bytes. I believe my edited answer removes all the spaces I can. :)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 84 bytes *.7=58.8 (bases 2 to 36)

```php
for(;($v=$argv)[2]>$a=$v[1]++;)$n+=substr_count(base_convert($a,10,$v[3]),0);echo$n;
```

or

```php
for(;($v=$argv)[2]>$v[1];)$n+=substr_count(base_convert($v[1]++,10,$v[3]),0);echo$n;
```

takes decimal input from command line arguments; run with `-r`.

Comment: For fun: `<?=0` supports unary and alphabetic. ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 102 bytes - 30% = 71.4

Why not.

```
(i,k,b)->{int j=0;for(;i<=k;i++)for(char c:Integer.toString(i,b).toCharArray())if(c==48)j++;return j;}
```

Without the bonus, 96 bytes (so the bonus actually improves my score!):

```
(i,k)->{int j=0;for(;i<=k;i++)for(char c:String.valueOf(i).toCharArray())if(c==48)j++;return j;}
```

This implements the following:

```
interface Function {
    public int apply(int i, int k, int b);
}
```

Comment: @mbomb007 The problem is that formatting it this way renders the answer as 102 bytes on the Leaderboard in the question.

Comment: That's a flaw with the leaderboard, not the post. Look at how most of the other answers are doing it the same way.

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm looking at the answers and I see a ton of different formats, some of which work with the leaderboard, some of which don't.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
#(count(re-seq #"0"(apply str(range %(inc %2)))))
```

Oh regex is shorter than filtering. Original:

```
#(count(filter #{\0}(apply str(range %(inc %2)))))
```

Very basic, uses the set of character `\0` to remove others and counts how many were found.